# Effects of a subwoofer on computer components

Tags: audio, components, hard-drive, motherboard

Ok so here's a question that I've only seen asked once, what are (if any) the adverse effects of having a subwoofer included in a PC case mod?

The Backstory:
I've got an OK case. Looks nice, has cool blue light effects, but I want to make it more unique to me. I figure, wouldn't it be epic to have a built in subwoofer/speaker set? So I went to FYE (for your entertainment) and they had a nice little speaker/sub combo for sale for $20. Now I'm thinking of mounting it in the side of my case (down by the PCI slots). Problem is, I don't want to start this project if this little 3" sub could royally screw any of the components up.

That being said, any thoughts/ideas/problems with the idea?

Comment: You want to know about audio effects? This is not a joke: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tDacjrSCeq4

Comment: That's a nice test, however, what would happen if those same disks were "vibration-proofed" (so to speak). Like in my response to Andy AKA below, I saw a suggestion to mount the hdd's with rubber grommets to prevent vibration. Think it might prevent that issue?

Comment: I love how someone -1'd my question. Just makes me more eager to try it (LOL).

Comment: '3" subwoofer' is a contradiction in terms.

Comment: Ribbon cables and delicate electronics make excellent low-frequency wave guides! ignore the naysayers

Comment: Sound is the vibration itself, sound travels in air, low-frequency sound travels without direction, so it'll be extremely difficult to isolate the HDD from all the vibrations (rubber grommets are far from enough - you saw in the video how shouting "travels" through air to hit the HDD?). Putting the HDD outside the room, and confining the sound into the room as much as possible might do the trick.

Comment: if sound would have that much of an effect on the hdd's that I'd need to put them in a different room, why can I keep the sub on the floor in the same room with no issue?

Answer (score 2):

Won't the sub-woofer need to be properly acoustically fitted-out into the case and this probably means reflex tubes, reflectors, dampeners etc? You know, the normal acoustic stuff to get it to work properly. If you do this then most of the acoustic output will go to the outside world. I'd worry about hard disks and your acoustic performance if you didn't: -

[image]

Comment: On the post I originally found (the link escapes me at the moment) someone suggested putting rubber grommets on the hdd's to prevent vibration (not sure if this works or not). I can probably mimic the acoustics of the subwoofer box, as it's literally a square box made of wood with a single sound output on the side, and a single output hole on the front. Here's the exact speaker set (so you can get a better idea): http://reviews.productwiki.com/cyber-acoustics-ca-3080/

Answer (score 2):

BAD idea. You won't be able to stop the PC case metalwork from rattling and even if you do, unless the side panels are extrusions rather than sheet metal, they won't be anywhere near rigid enough.

It may **look** cool but it won't work nearly as well as a subwoofer as you want, regardless of the effect on the hard disk.

I have seen vibration from [good speakers](http://www.markhennessy.co.uk/rogers/ls58.htm) (*without* subwoofers!) move a coffee cup around a table when driven fairly hard. OK, this was a demonstration of what 115dBa sounded like, but I don't want to imagine the vibration effects on a HDD in the same enclosure...

EDIT: If you proceed with this idea, consider a solid state drive, and an external USB drive or NAS for bulk storage and backup.

Rubber gasket is good. Also use [bitumen sound deadening pads](http://www.newtoncomm.co.uk/products/24-products-24/) on all sheet metal panels. Although they are automotive product they are the same pads used in that loudspeaker (classic BBC practice). I used them in a prototype (pre-Rogers) pair of the smaller [LS5/9](http://www.markhennessy.co.uk/rogers/ls59.htm) which I assembled at work and veneered at home. (the BBC had quite a relaxed attitude to "home office" projects as long as they didn't pay for parts and you worked on your own time)

Comment: That is a giant a** speaker (lol). Didn't think about the rattling of the case. Although thinking of it, I could put some rubber gasket around all the removable metal parts to dampen the vibrations.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I haven't begun the project (except to strip the sub and speakers from their infernal packaging). At this point, I'm still looking at how I might keep my HDD's safe from harm. Only thing I've come up with is to seal them off from the rest of the case (which i'm not entirely sure is a good idea... or possible for that matter...)